# Secure? Converting Excel functions into Web Script

Tags: java, php, sql, database, excel

I understand that I can convert Excel files into web scripts through converters such as Apache POI (into Java) or PHPExcel (into PHP). However, the Excel file I am trying to convert contains a lot of trade secret and proprietary information. How can I secure it?

For example, if I have excel function "11+a=b," I want the website user to enter "value A," press calculate, and webpage return "Answer B" to the user without letting the user know the formula "11+a=b."

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misunderstood what these libraries do.

They allow you to read Excel documents so you can access the raw contents of e.g. cells from within your own program.  If you need to do anything more than that - like recalculating the value displayed of a cell - you need to provide additional code yourself.

Comment: thanks, then I assume there isn't an existing project that can help me with what I am trying to do?

Comment: or, if these libraries can only "read" the excel doc.
Can't I simply have "Value A" as a pull down menu (with 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6...etc.) in the doc? That would still be only reading the doc not, manipulating it in anyway.
If that is doable, can the functions be protected?

Comment: I do not know.  Perhaps open a new question asking specifically for that functionality.